# Closed $n$ form from Harvard Qualifying Exam

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

In the most recent Harvard Qualifying exam, one is asked to prove that if $M$ is a compact oriented manifold, and there are two nonvanishing orientation forms $\xi$ and $\eta$ who's integrals over $M$ agree, then there exists a diffeomorphism $F:M\rightarrow M$ such that
$F^*\eta=\xi$

I understand everything but one step in the solution. Let me elaborate, we first show that there exists an $n-1$  form $\sigma$ such that:
\begin{align*}
d\sigma=\xi-\eta
\end{align*}
which follows from the fact that the Cohomology class defined by $\xi-\eta$ is zero.

At some point later in the proof, we examine the manifold $\tilde{M}=M\times [0,\infty)$, where the $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ part of the manifold is represented in coordinates with a $t$. Denote by $\xi$, $\eta$ and $\sigma$ the pull back of $\xi$, $\eta$, and $\sigma$ by the projection $\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$, and define the $n$ form $\omega$ by:

\begin{align*}
\omega=(1-t)\xi+t\eta
\end{align*}
Now the claim is that this one form is closed, but I am not seeing how. In particular, I can write this $n$ form as:
\begin{align*}
\omega=t\xi -td\sigma
\end{align*}
Since the pull backs of $\xi$ and $\sigma$ have no $t$ dependence, it follows that:

\begin{align*}
d\omega=dt\wedge \xi+td\xi-dt\wedge d\sigma
\end{align*}
Now $\xi=d\sigma+\eta$ so:
\begin{align*}
d\omega=dt\wedge \eta+td\xi
\end{align*}
and $d\xi=d\eta$ so:
\begin{align*}
d\omega=dt\wedge \eta+td\eta=d(t\eta)
\end{align*}
which does not look like it is closed to me. Have I made some blunder here?

Edit:

It should indeed by:
\begin{align*}
\omega=\xi-td\sigma
\end{align*}
Taking the exterior derivative gives:
\begin{align*}
d\omega =&d\xi-dt \wedge d\sigma\\
=&d\xi -dt\wedge \xi+dt\wedge \eta
\end{align*}
but this also does not seem closed.

Comment: Should it not be $\omega = \xi - t\,d\sigma$ ?

Comment: $d\omega = d(dt\wedge\sigma)$, so $\omega-dt\wedge\sigma$ is closed?

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Updated, thanks for the catch. It still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you saying that $\omega$ is not closed?

Comment: $\omega$ is definitely not closed.

Comment: Unfortunate, because this method of proof seems to hinge on that fact, at least from the solution.

Comment: But is it possible that this solution is incorrect? It seems like this problem has a rather straightforward solution.

Comment: @Deane They walk you through it step by step like this, this is part $c)$, I skipped be $b)$ in my question bc it was irrelevant to the closedeness of $\omega$. What’s your straightforward solution though?

Comment: Perhaps you could present their proof? The main point is that you need to construct a diffeomorphism $F$ and you do it by constructing a 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $F_t$, where $F_0 = I$ and $F_1$ is the desired diffeomorphism. I did a sketch, and it seemed easy. On the other hand, if it's really as easy as I think, then the problem seems too easy for a Harvard quals problem.

Comment: I found the question and solution. It's the first problem on Day 3 of the Spring 2023 exam https://live-hu-math.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/quals-S23.pdf. The proof is more or less how I envisioned it, but the details of part c) do look pretty involved. I do wonder, however, if the details might be clearer if everything were written with respect to local coordinates.

Comment: @Deane. , I get everything they’re doing except when they say $\omega$ is closed

Comment: Have you tried to fix the proof yourself?

Comment: Not yet, I was pretty hung up on the closed part. I’ll try though.

Comment: Yeah, never trust anyone else's proof. Just try to get the gist of what they're trying to do but work out the details yourself.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the well-known method of Moser's trick, and that's likely the point of this exercise. This is actually part of a stronger theorem proved by Moser and appearing in the very same paper as his eponymous trick, I believe. (The title of the paper is has "volume elements" or "volume forms" in its title, I don't remember off the top of my head.) As for annoying smoothness details, your $\omega$ is a volume form for all $t\in[0,1]$ and remains so (by a compactness argument) for all $t\in(-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.